# Visual Studio-> Find all references-> Looking for symbol in XAML files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, find-all-references

Is there a way to prevent "Find all references" from searching in XAML files?  Searching the XAML files is painfully slow.

Comment: I hope you reported this to Microsoft.

Comment: I had checked there first, no workarounds posted so I checked here.

Here's the ms connect link for your reference:  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/553562/unnecessary-looking-for-symbol-in-xaml-files

Answer (score 2):

Not to re-open an older post, but you could do a "find in files" and specify only the file types you want to search through (e.g. .xml; .txt; .cs; .cpp etc).

Granted i might be stating the obvious but....